# SCSS variables do not work in conjunction with prefers-color-scheme: dark

Tags: css, variables, sass, darkmode

I'm currently experimenting a bit with the CSS feature `prefers-color-scheme`.
Since I'm using `SCSS`, I declare all the colors I use at the beginning. So here's what I did:

```
$textColor: #1B1C1E;
$hoverColor: #0203048a;

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  $textColor: #FAFAFA;
  $hoverColor: #BBC6C6;
}
```

When I then try the whole dark mode thing, prefers-color-scheme: dark is ignored and the colors are displayed as without preferd-color-scheme. I test the whole thing in Chrome and use the Dev Tool to emulate the CSS feature.


Does anyone know why this is? Can't I use SCSS variables in conjunction with preferd-color-scheme?


The only solution so far would be to put all the code that is changed in darkmode into the `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {}` part. But this is a bit time-consuming, if you have to do this for every change.

Comment: So i found a "solution" in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60456346/how-to-set-light-and-dark-modes-with-scss-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said before, I found the solution in [another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60456346/how-to-set-light-and-dark-modes-with-scss-variables).

Here the content briefly summarized:

TL;DR: **When converting SCSS to CSS, the SCSS variables (i.e. the ones with `$` in front of the name) are not converted as well.**

In order to use variables that also work with CSS, they must be declared with `--` (instead of `$`).

To use them then `var(--varName)` is specified.